# how to convert tilted wave to straight wave line in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have 2 column of vectors which are Position and Time. After I plot the position vs time as you could see in the picture it is tilted wave shape which is true according my data. I would like to have this wave shape in the straight line not tilted like below figure. Could I convert this shape to straight line wave?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: How about doing a simple linear regression and then subtracting the line of best fit? Check the `fitlm` function for this or if your Matlab is old you can use the `regress` function.

Comment: @Dan I have matlab R2013b but fitlm is not working on it!!

Comment: it should be, although perhaps it's in the stats toolbox, maybe you don't have it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is [this](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/signal/examples/peak-analysis.html#zmw57dd0e677) tutorial on peak analysis in the mathworks docs which discribes(in a sitenote) how to detrend data (by doing what Dan suggested):

```
load noisyecg.mat
t = 1:length(noisyECG_withTrend); 
plot(t,noisyECG_withTrend)        %load the data with trend

[p,s,mu] = polyfit((1:numel(noisyECG_withTrend))',noisyECG_withTrend,6);
f_y = polyval(p,(1:numel(noisyECG_withTrend))',[],mu);     %fitting a polynom in that data

ECG_data = noisyECG_withTrend - f_y;        % Detrend data by subtracting the values of said polynom
```